# Como faço pra somar números no innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, brasil

O código não esta somando,só juntando (concatenando*) os números

```js
var media = "";
var media2 = "";
var media3 = "";
var media4 = "";

function myFunction(){

media = Number(document.getElementById("vnota").value);
media2 = Number(document.getElementById("vnota2").value);
media3 = Number(document.getElementById("vnota3").value);
media4 = Number(document.getElementById("vnota4").value);

document.getElementById("notas").innerHTML = "A sua nota final é: " + media + media2 + media3 + media4;


}
```

Comment: "Juntando" você quer dizer "concatenando", não é?

Comment: Tenta colocar a soma entre parênteses (`"A sua nota final é: " + (media + media2 + media3 + media4)`). Se não você pode somar antes e salvar numa variável, `total`, por exemplo

Comment: Deu certo,obrigado mano! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var media = "";  //Apenas uma variável é necessária, vc só precisa ir 
                 //somando a cada nova nota;

function myFunction(){

media = Number(document.getElementById("vnota").value);
media += Number(document.getElementById("vnota2").value);
media += Number(document.getElementById("vnota3").value);
media += Number(document.getElementById("vnota4").value);

document.getElementById("notas").innerHTML = "A sua nota final é:" +media ;


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pode criar uma variável total  o códico ficaria assim
total = (media + media2) + media3 + media4 e a variável total tem que ser declarada dentro da função MyFunction
dps só escrever ela no innerHTML pouparia esse monte de média no innerHTML.